# Object Orientated Socket Python Client Server. Pass Modified Client Message to Server

Tags: python, sockets, oop, server, echo

I am trying to build a Python program that will pass a message between a Client and Server. The idea is to pass one message from the Server and have the Client modify it and pass it back to the Server.

Right now I am suck on trying to get the Client's message back to the Server; the message 'Congrats! You have connected' is converted to uppercase,

Server

```
import socket

class Server:

    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

    def bind(self):
        self.serverSocket.bind((self.host, self.port))
        self.serverSocket.listen(5)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print ('Waiting for a connection')
            (clientSocket, addr) = self.serverSocket.accept()
            print ('Got a connection from {}'.format(str(addr)))
            message = 'Congrats! You have connected'
            self.sendMessage(message, clientSocket)
            self.recieveMessage()
            clientSocket.close()

    def sendMessage(self, message, clientSocket):
        clientSocket.send(message.encode('ascii'))

    def recieveMessage(self):
        (clientSocket, addr) = self.serverSocket.accept()
        message = self.serverSocket.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
        print(message)

    def closeSocket(self):
        self.serverSocket.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    myServer = Server('127.0.0.1', 5555)
    myServer.bind()
    myServer.run()
    myServer.recieveMessage()
    myServer.closeSocket()
```

Client

```
import socket


class Client:

    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

    def connect(self):
        self.serverSocket.connect((self.host, self.port))

    def getMessage(self):
        return self.serverSocket.recv(1024).decode('ascii')

    def modifyMessage(self):
        return message.upper()

    def sendMessage(self, upperCaseMessage, server):
        (server, addr) = self.serverSocket.accept()
        serverSocket.send(upperCaseMessage.encode('ascii'))

    def closeConnection(self):
        self.serverSocket.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    myClient = Client('127.0.0.1', 5555)
    myClient.connect()
    message = myClient.getMessage()
    upperCaseMessage = myClient.modifyMessage()
    myClient.sendMessage(upperCaseMessage, serverSocket)
    myClient.closeConnection()
```

Comment: The code as you posted does not work, what is `serverSocket` that you pass to the `sendMessage` method in the second-last line?

Comment: I'm really new to Python in an object orientated way, and the code above is probably really, really wrong. I was trying to pass the port and host in order to be able to pass the message back to the Server.